# If generics are computed as compile time, why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have 2 classes like this:

```
public class Circle {
  private int area;

  public Circle(int a) {
    area = a;
  }

  public int getArea() {
    System.out.println("Circle::getArea");
    return area;
  }
}

public class Square {
  private int area;

  public Square(int a) {
    area = a;
  }

  public int getArea() {
    System.out.println("Square::getArea");
    return area;
  }
}
```

I'd like to write something like

```
  public static <T> int genericArea(T shape) {
    return shape.getArea();
  }
```

But that fails with `error: cannot find symbol`

It was my understanding that because generics are solved at compile time it should be able to verify that all usages of that method are with Square or Circle class.

fiddle here: https://repl.it/repls/InnocentDarkmagentaDifferences

Note that I know how I would do it with interfaces, but:
1. I'm curious
2. In the specific problem I'm trying to solve, I cannot modify Circle and Square because they are auto-generated by some other system

Comment: So you getting the compile error `error: cannot find symbol` ? then that makes sense, how does it how the shape type of T is either Circle or Square? what if you pass `Cat` class into the `genericArea` which doesnt have getArea method, so this compile error says it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ uses *templates*; it creates a separate copy (originally, in generated source code) of `genericArea` for each use. That means that you can use any type that has `getArea()` for it.

Java uses *generics* instead; there is only one copy of the `genericArea` method, and it can handle anything that matches its type parameter. But your type parameter is essentially just `Object` since you haven't limited it to something like `T extends HasArea`, and there's no `Object.getArea()`.

Comment: This answers the question I asked "why".

Comment: Write an interface (or abstract base class) that both classes implement (or extend), then make that the upper bound for `T`.

Comment: @Choumarin Without modifying those other classes _somehow_, the answer is "you can't".

Comment: Noted. How dirty would it be to use reflection?

Comment: @Choumarin You're getting into clear XY territory at this point.